# Protect the program before turning it back on

Tags: bash, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

My script is executed by Cron and every 2 min checks if xxx is running. If it is not in the process then the script will run it. The problem is that sometimes it runs it several times.

My problem is how to detect that the program is running several times?
How does bash detect that the pidof function returns several rather than one pid?

```
#!/bin/bash
PID=`pidof xxx`
if [ "$PID" = "" ];
then
cd
cd /home/pi
sudo ./xxx
echo "OK"
else
echo "program is running"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script for doing the same. It will make sure script is executed once.

```
#!/bin/bash
ID=`ps -ef|grep scriptname|grep -v grep|wc -l`
if [ $ID -eq 0 ];
then
#run the script
else
echo "script is running"
fi
```